# Is there any trait that specifies numeric functionality?

Tags: rust, numeric, generic-programming, traits

I'd like to use a trait to bound a generic type, like this hypothetical `HasSQRT`:

```
fn some_generic_function<T>(input: &T)
where
    T: HasSQRT,
{
    // ...
    input.sqrt()
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) or [num-traits](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) crates and bound your generic function type with [`num::Float`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.Float.html), [`num::Integer`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.Integer.html) or whatever relevant trait:

```
use num::Float; // 0.2.1

fn main() {
    let f1: f32 = 2.0;
    let f2: f64 = 3.0;
    let i1: i32 = 3;

    println!("{:?}", sqrt(f1));
    println!("{:?}", sqrt(f2));
    println!("{:?}", sqrt(i1)); // error
}

fn sqrt<T: Float>(input: T) -> T {
    input.sqrt()
}
```

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour use dependencies. Rust is unlike many other languages in that package management is built in and strongly embraced. The canonical example is random number generation, which is provided in a crate and not the standard library.

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour It is understandable to desire minimizing dependencies, but as Shepmaster said, Rust makes dependency management convenient to encourage people to use them. Plus, the `num` crate is very well maintained, it will not be abandoned.

Comment: @Kroltan I'm coming from C++ background, in there adding every dependency was a scary decision. I can guess only those libraries that are bound to C libraries are the ones I should avoid to add, am I correct?

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour I'd avoid dependencies that are not in pure stable rust.