# How can I explain to the compiler that a generic function returns data which can be used in subtraction?

Tags: rust

I get error if use a generic realization for a generic structure. How should I explain to the compiler that the `last` function returns data which can be used in subtraction operation?

```
use std::ops::Sub;

struct Container<A, B>(A, B);

trait Contains {
    type A;
    type B;

    fn contains(&self, &Self::A, &Self::B) -> bool;
    fn first(&self) -> Self::A;
    fn last(&self) -> Self::B;
}

impl<C: PartialEq, D: PartialEq + Sub> Contains for Container<C, D> {
    type A = C;
    type B = D;

    fn contains(&self, number_1: &Self::A, number_2: &Self::B) -> bool {
        (&self.0 == number_1) && (&self.1 == number_2)
    }
    fn first(&self) -> Self::A {
        self.0
    }
    fn last(&self) -> Self::B {
        self.1
    }
}

fn difference<C: Contains>(container: &C) -> i32 {
    container.last() - container.first()
}

fn main() {
    let number_1 = 3;
    let number_2 = 10;

    let container = Container(number_1, number_2);

    println!("Does container contain {} and {}: {}",
             &number_1,
             &number_2,
             container.contains(&number_1, &number_2));
    println!("First number: {}", container.first());
    println!("Last number: {}", container.last());

    println!("The difference is: {}", difference(&container));
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `-` cannot be applied to type `<C as Contains>::B`
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 |     container.last() - container.first()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Sub` might be missing for `<C as Contains>::B`
```

Comment: Highly related if not a duplicate [Requiring implementation of Mul in generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/155423)

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun bit of type tetris to figure out :)

Someone else may be able to weigh in on a better way to implement what you're trying to do, but I can at least explain why your code isn't compiling.

There's four issues:

- Your implementation of `difference` is generic over all implementations of `Contains`, therefore it's not enough to just put a constraint on `Container`'s types - you need to put them on the trait itself as well.
- Because you're trying to subtract an object of type `Self::A` from an object of type `Self::B`, you need to specify that in the constraint - it defaults to being `Sub<Self>`.
- Rust won't implicitly convert the result of `difference` to an `i32` - you either need to be generic over the return value of `difference`, or add an explicit conversion (which will involve adding more type constraints). I did the former, as it seems more in keeping with what you're trying to achieve.
- `first` and `last` try to move ownership of `self.0` and `self.1` out of the struct - you need to either have them return borrows (which will involve lifetime shenanigans), or restrict `Contains` to only allow `Copy` types.

With those changes made, your code will look like this:

```
use std::ops::Sub;

struct Container<A, B>(A, B);

trait Contains {
    type A: Copy + PartialEq;
    type B: Copy + PartialEq + Sub<Self::A>;

    fn contains(&self, &Self::A, &Self::B) -> bool;
    fn first(&self) -> Self::A;
    fn last(&self) -> Self::B;
}

impl<C, D> Contains for Container<C, D>
where
    C: Copy + PartialEq,
    D: Copy + PartialEq + Sub<C>,
{
    type A = C;
    type B = D;

    fn contains(&self, number_1: &Self::A, number_2: &Self::B) -> bool {
        (&self.0 == number_1) && (&self.1 == number_2)
    }
    fn first(&self) -> Self::A {
        self.0
    }
    fn last(&self) -> Self::B {
        self.1
    }
}

fn difference<C: Contains>(
    container: &C,
) -> <<C as Contains>::B as std::ops::Sub<<C as Contains>::A>>::Output {
    container.last() - container.first()
}

fn main() {
    let number_1 = 3;
    let number_2 = 10;

    let container = Container(number_1, number_2);

    println!(
        "Does container contain {} and {}: {}",
        &number_1,
        &number_2,
        container.contains(&number_1, &number_2)
    );
    println!("First number: {}", container.first());
    println!("Last number: {}", container.last());

    println!("The difference is: {}", difference(&container));
}
```

Which compiles and runs fine:

```
Does container contain 3 and 10: true
First number: 3
Last number: 10
The difference is: 7
```

I'd note that if `Contains` is *always* going to contain only numeric types, you'll probably be able to implement this far easier using the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num), as shown in [Trait for numeric functionality in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296351/trait-for-numeric-functionality-in-rust).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much -:). When I can more read about that constraints which you have used in `associated types` and function `difference`? I read official docs but that syntax there isn't appeared.

Comment: @MrEfrem: I figured it out based off the Rust docs, the compiler errors and a bit of trial and error :p See [`Sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Sub.html) and [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).