# Why doesn't the comparison operation in my iterator filter over generic types work?

Tags: filter, iterator, rust

I am trying to understand why the following code does not compile ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3e93c5b7784f83bd3c79e295f52e3948&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
fn inspection<I>(iter: I)
where 
    I: Iterator, 
    I::Item: Ord,
{
    let inspection = iter
        .filter(|x| x > 0);
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    inspection(data.iter()); // or inspection(data.into_iter());
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:25
  |
9 |         .filter(|x| x > 0);
  |                         ^ expected reference, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `&<I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item`
             found type `{integer}`
```

I tried to follow the various alternatives (by de-referencing the element) as explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) without success.

First attempt:

```
.filter(|x| **x > 0);
```

```
error[E0614]: type `<I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:13:21
   |
13 |         .filter(|x| **x > 0);
   |
```

Second attempt:

```
.filter(|&x| *x > 0);
```

```
error[E0614]: type `<I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:13:22
   |
13 |         .filter(|&x| *x > 0);
   |
```

Why is the program not compiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue (the other problem was covered by Lukas) is that you are comparing the iterator's generic items with an integer while comparisons provided by `PartialOrd`/`Ord` only work between the same types:

```
pub trait Ord: Eq + PartialOrd<Self> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering;
    ...
}
```

In order for a type `T` to be comparable with a number (in this case `0`), `T` must be a number and `0` needs to be of type `T` too. The `num` crate containing useful numeric traits can help here with its [`Zero`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Zero.html) trait that provides a generic `0`:

```
extern crate num;

use num::Zero;

fn inspection<'a, I, T: 'a>(iter: I)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    T: Zero + PartialOrd // T is an ordered number
{
    let inspection = iter.filter(|&x| *x > T::zero()); // T::zero() is 0 of the same type as T
}

fn main() {
    let data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    inspection(data.iter());
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the whole `Num` there, though, wouldn't `Zero` and `PartialOrd` be sufficient?

Comment: I am not quite convinced, when I call the function with a vector of `i32` the types are the same.

Comment: @Nick yes, but the function is not defined *only* for `i32` - it is generic and must typecheck for any other type that can be applied to it. Not all types implementing `Ord` (e.g. `char`) can be compared with a `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You were really close to solving the first problem! You tried:

- `filter(|x| x > 0)`
- `filter(|x| **x > 0)`
- `filter(|&x| *x > 0)`

**The solution is: `filter(|x| *x > 0)` *or* `filter(|&x| x > 0)`.**

To see why, let's take a close look at the error message again:

```
9 |         .filter(|x| x > 0);
  |                         ^ expected reference, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `&<I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item`
             found type `{integer}`
```

It says that it expected the type `&<I as std::iter::Iterator>::Item` and got the type `{integer}`. This means that the difference is *one* reference. You cannot compare `&i32` to `i32`. So you can remove the one `&` by using either `*` (the dereference operator) or the `|&x|` pattern (which dereferences the value too). But if you combine both, this has the same effect as `**`: it tries to dereferences twice. Which is not possible because the type only contains one reference.

---

However, it still doesn't compile due to a more complicated issue. You can read more about it here:

- [Trait for numeric functionality in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296351/trait-for-numeric-functionality-in-rust)

Comment: Those two alternatives unfortunately do not work as well: `expected associated type, found integral variable` (https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=74042c8d0d2da9c8e248439b22a9656b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: @Nick Oops, my bad! I mentioned the second problem now.