# Is there a trait in Rust representing integers, e.g. i32, i64, u8, u16, ...?

Tags: generics, rust

I am writing a radix sort function in Rust that can handle vectors containing i32, i64, u8, u16, or so on. I did not find any trait that can represent integers, so initially I tried `T: Into<isize> + From<isize>`, but `From<isize>` is not implemented for u8 or for a bunch of other types. I wonder if there is one trait that is implemented by all the primitive integer types and can be used here? Or what should the bound be if there is none?

P.S. I also tried `T: Div<isize> + Rem<isize>`, but the compiler said that the `<T as Div>::Output` and `<T as Rem>::Output` cannot be used as array index.

Comment: The question in the title is answered by [Is there any trait that specifies numeric functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296351/is-there-any-trait-that-specifies-numeric-functionality), but you may have an XY problem. Please show us what exactly you tried to achieve that depends on integers generically.

Comment: `isize` is not guaranteed to be the largest integer size. I'd recommend `i64` (which will be the same size or larger) or `i128` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there is one trait that is implemented by all the primitive integer types and can be used here?

The `num` crate provides such a trait, but I'm not sure it would be terribly useful to you here.  It sounds like at the end of your operation, you need a `usize` to be able to index an array, so you want to accept "some integer type," do some math with it, then get a `usize` out the other end.

You might be interested in the [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) trait, which is like `Into` but specifies a possibly-fallible conversion.  If you make your own function fallible, this would be an appropriate way to accept multiple integer types.

The `Div` and `Rem` bounds need to specify the output type, because right now the output is unbounded meaning you could get *any* type from their invocations; it wouldn't even have to be a numeric type.

However, assuming you need to keep `isize` as the intermediate type, you could just do something like this and forgo the `Div` and `Rem` bounds entirely:

```
enum FooError {
    IntConversion,
    OutOfSliceBounds,
}

fn foo<T: TryInto<isize>, V>(n: T, slice: &[V]) -> Result<&V, FooError>
{
    let n: isize = n.try_into().map_err(|_| FooError::IntConversion)?;
    
    // Do some math on n, then...
    let n: usize = n.try_into().map_err(|_| FooError::IntConversion)?;
    
    slice.get(n).ok_or(FooError::OutOfSliceBounds)
}
```

If `isize` is not large enough to be the intermediate type you could use a larger integer type, but to index a slice you have to be able to convert the final result to `usize`.

If the domain of `usize` is suitable for the math operations, you could just accept `T: TryInto<usize>` and then you don't need the second conversion at all.